# ko.DirtyFlag on ko.observableArray is always dirty

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray, kolite

Inside my viewmodel I have following code:

```
var self = this;
self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
var mapped = $.map(data.Addresses, function (item) { return new Address(item) });
self.AddressList = ko.observableArray(mapped);
self.dirtyFlag = new ko.DirtyFlag([self.Name, self.AddressList]);
```

I always get the dirty flag true due to `AddressList`.

Is there a way to specify what value is not dirty or when to start monitoring for change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like maybe something in your address is bound to a `select` with the `value` binding and it is writing a value on the initial binding. It will change numbers to strings. You could always choose to call `reset` on the flag after applying bindings (call `self.dirtyFlag.reset()`